# How to use ng-repeat to correctly display twitter bootstrap labels?

Tags: angularjs

Seems to be a simple task. But `ng-repeat` on `span` tag will create consecutive `<span>`s without a space.

```
<span class="label label-success" ng-repeat="r in roles">
```

If those `<span>` tags connect to each other without a space or line break, those labels will look merged together (especially in Chrome).

See my example here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AFMHnxsLk4EjDFQWsZVv?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add margin to the right side

```
.label.label-success {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

if you don't want spacing after the last one, you can simply do:

```
.label.label-success:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Note [:last-of-type](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20selectors) is only supported in modern browsers

Edit after Morgan's comment

```
.label.label-success:after {
    content:"&nbsp;"
}
```

Could be a better solution depending on what kind of spacing your after.

Comment: This is unnatural; it doesn't rely on the size of the font to determine the space between `<span>s`. But I do usually like CSS solutions.

Comment: Upvote for the `content:"&nbsp;"`. And this does protect the html side from being polluted. New knowledge learned. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't place spaces in between `ng-repeat` elements by design. What you really want to repeat is a `<span>` followed by an `&nbsp;`. Try wrapping those 2 items within an `ng-repeat` element.

```
<span ng-repeat="r in roles"><span class="label label-success">{{r}}</span>&nbsp;</span>
```

[Try this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d41F1J1iGGGwFkjeXg9U?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. That is a smart tweak. That nested `span` tags work but it does look a bit ugly. Let's see if there is any better answer.